# How to optimize a query on a large table, besides using index?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, optimization, table

I need suggestions/ideas of optimizing the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT 1 
      FROM f 
      WHERE parent_sha256 = $1 
        AND parent_sha256 <> sha256 
      LIMIT 1) AS row_count;
```

Which is needed to verify if a specific parent_sha256 has any direct childs.
The table is very large (50M rows), and the query is very slow (6-12 min) when there are 700k~900k rows that match `parent_sha256 = $1` but 0 rows that match `parent_sha256 = $1 AND parent_sha256 <> sha256`.

In that case the DB has to go over all the 700k~900k.

It's worth mentioning that there are indexes on `parent_sha256` and `sha256`.

Comment: Can you define a combined index on (parent_sha256, sha256)?

Comment: @AndreaB. no, since (parent_sha256, sha256) isn't unique.

Comment: It doesn't need to be unique. You just need a single index with both columns, in that order, instead of two separate indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON f (parent_sha256) WHERE parent_sha256 <> sha256;
```

The trick here is that the executor doesn't have to evaluate the costly condition `parent_sha256 <> sha256` (which requires looking at all rows that satisfy `parent_sha256 = $1`), because rows that do not meet the condition `parent_sha256 <> sha256` are not indexed and are automatically skipped by the index scan.

Comment: Thanks!. Since this index is very costly I've created the index `CONCURRENTLY`, and noticed the huge performance impact right away.

Answer (score 4):

The [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) provided by [Laurenz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/176905/laurenz-albe) has huge impact.

To address "besides using index": simplify the convoluted query for additional tiny improvement.

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM f 
   WHERE  parent_sha256 = $1 
   AND    parent_sha256 <> sha256 
   );
```

Returns `true` / `false` instead of `1`/`0` in your original.
If `true` / "no row" works for you:

```
SELECT true
FROM   f
WHERE  parent_sha256 = $1 
AND    parent_sha256 <> sha256 
LIMIT  1;
```